# Android show animated WebP

Tags: android, webp

I have an animated webp file that I took from the original [AR Stickers APK](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/ar-stickers/ar-stickers-1-0-171127163-release/ar-stickers-1-0-171127163-android-apk-download/) which I'd like to show in my app for onboarding in ARCore. It looks like I can easily load the first frame of the webp file into an imageview but trying to decode it as a `Movie` object fails. Is there a simple way of showing it? It's obviously possible since the AR-Stickers app clearly did it in their original release. I saw that there's a library from Facebook (Fresco) that seems like it should be able to do it but from what I understand it adds quite a bit of bloat to my app's APK. Are there any simple solutions to this?

Answer (score 10):

That's true. There aren't many animated WebP/GIF solutions out there, and Fresco takes a lot.

There is [**this library**](http://github.com/McoyJiang/Android-WebP)  (made an easier fork of it [here](http://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/Android-WebP) ), but it can have some serious issues with files sometimes, such as [here](http://github.com/McoyJiang/Android-WebP/issues/7) . If you know why this occurs, and how to fix it, please consider contributing to it (or to my fork).

There is, of course, a way to use the normal Android framework for loading animation files (sample [**here**](https://medium.com/appnroll-publication/what-is-new-in-android-p-imagedecoder-animatedimagedrawable-a65744bec7c1)) using ImageDecoder&AnimatedImageDrawable , but it's only from Android P.

Google has promised it will be added to the support library ([**here**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78041382#comment3)), but I still don't see it.

That's why I've created a question [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53024304/878126), where I wanted to know how to fetch frame-by-frame image of an animated WebP file.

Comment: Any idea of the issue？

Comment: @peerless2012 What do you mean?

Comment: The [Android-WebP#issue7](https://github.com/McoyJiang/Android-WebP/issues/7) display error.

Comment: @peerless2012 I just don't use this library anywhere. If you want to view the animation or have frame-by-frame of it, you can check somewhere else that I wrote about it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53234195/878126 . Others also show solutions. Not sure which is the best

Comment: You webp glide plugin project, i have see it before and it is amazing.  I just find that you use libWebP too, and i will check that project. Thanks for your work.

Comment: @peerless2012 I'm sure there is a better solution instead of the weird thing I've done. One that directly fetches the frames. It's inside Glide and the other library of WEBP.

Comment: It sounds great, and i'll glad to talk about that with you somewhere.

Comment: @peerless2012 If you have a nice solution that doesn't require the weird parts that I made, please write it there.