# How to resize GIF/Animated WebP image files in Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gif, webp

How can we resize the animated image files like gif, animated webp or animated png files in android ? I am not asking about showing animation on Image View. My goal is to save the animated image file on storage after resizing.

I tried glide but we have to write complex code to get bitmap of each frame and then fit that bitmap to specific size or crop it then encode all those frames back into an animated image file.

There is another lib called imagemagick but android version has some issue that i could not use it

APNG4ANDROID is another library which looks perfect for this operation but it has also some issues although its good lib for showing animated images. it is not meant for this resize stuff

Comment: If size of the apk doesn't matter for you, you can use ffmpeg

Comment: Thanks for comment. Yeah I could use that but I tried ffmpeg in React Native and achive the goal with gif files but cannot resize the animated webp file. I came to know that it does not have animated webp decoder so it can only resize the gif and encode to animated webp.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question. Asking for "suggestions" makes it seem like you are asking for a library which is off-topic for SO.  I suggest you either add more details, what have you tried, why did that not work etc, if this is really a *programming question*. Or, ask for a library on [Software Recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com). 

Comment: Found this question, it looks like it's possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53024304

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution after lots of searching and exxperimenting.

For Gif:

- Extract frames from gif using decoder
- Resize the each bitmaps.
- encode them into webp or gif using encoder

For Webp:

- (Need Glid) use given code to extract frames as bitmaps.
- Resize them
- encode into gif/webp

(Delay is also available to use it with encoder)

Gif encoder decoder
https://github.com/waynejo/android-ndk-gif

Webp Ecnoder
https://github.com/b4rtaz/android-webp-encoder

Webp decoding using Glide:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64744296/9308731

Resizing:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32810187/9308731